# Strange behaviour for MongoDB covered query

Tags: mongodb

If I have the following collection

```
{ "_id" : "a" }
{ "_id" : "b" }
{ "_id" : "c" }
```

#### Normal query

If I now run the following query

```
db.test.find({_id: "a"}, {_id: 1}).explain("executionStats")
```

It returns

```
"executionStats" : {
    "totalKeysExamined" : 1,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 1
}
```

#### Query with hint

Now for the strange part. If I run the following query

```
db.test.find({_id: "a"}, {_id: 1}).hint({_id: 1}).explain("executionStats")
```

It returns

```
"executionStats" : {
    "totalKeysExamined" : 1,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 0
}
```

#### Question

Why is the normal query examining a document, even if I only want the _id?

Server version: v3.2.1

Comment: Was that to obtuse? I'll try to be more obvious. *"What is the general intent of looking up a document by a primary key?"* and that basically means you can only return one thing. If then you are looking up one document only by that one value, then *"is it really important to optimally return the result with the value you just asked for?"*. This should be a resounding **NO** to any reasonable person. If you look up something by the "primary key", you generally want the whole document. Or at the very least you are interested in other data than just the primary key itself.

Comment: I have a collection of users and the _id is the username. To check whether the username is available i do a query on _id. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Please stop and listen and think. You are asking: *"If I ask for `_id` equal to `1`, why does the default case look at the whole document and not just `_id`?"*. Consider that "covered queries" are really most useful for "range" information. If you ask for exact matches, then other than "counts" of results, what useful information is being returned? Primary key lookups **"mostly"** want to look at other data in the document. Hence, that is the "optimal" default behaviour. For most normal people that is.

Comment: I see. This makes sense. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is that you are generally using the _id index instead of going through the collection. You get to see the indexes using

```
collection.getIndexes()
```

In that sense the mongo server (query optimizer) used the index specified (_id) and did not have to go through the collection

Hop that helps

Comment: But why does it examinate the document in the first query? There is no need to do that.

Comment: This does not really answer the question that was asked. I only didn't post as an answer since it is actually a common idiom in database circles that primary key lookups ( or any unique key ) are meant to pull documents (rows)  and not simply return a single document ( row ) with the same field value ( and just that field ) you just asked for. Which most would admit is fairly useless information to ask of a database in the first place.

Comment: as far as my understanding goes; 1) there is no index to use (assuming you did not create one) so it searches through every single document. 2) to have a better understanding use explain("allPlansExecution")

Comment: Then your understanding of both the question and principles would both be wrong. There is some material posted here you should read.

Comment: @BlakesSeven fair enough. I replied though. as far as I understood. JST wanted to understand the approach to thinking about using hint() not specifically the concept of primary keys. _id. at anycase If am wrong in my answer I will appreciate it if you could direct me to the right path. I am always learning :).

Comment: I now use a separate indexed field for this and leave the _id field with the default ObjectID. Thank you guys

Comment: There is an actual reason for the case ( which was basically explained in the comments ) which is all about searching on `_id`, which being the primary key is **always** indexed. Therefore your learn something  for today can be "primary keys are always indexed, so I don't need to check if it's indexed". Hence, why you really did not address the question.